# Titanium Studio android app crashing by pressing android back button?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing android app using Titanium Studio 3.2.1, but here when I am changing my tabs app getting crash. So jumped into Ti 3.1.3, here when I am changing my tabs first time it is showing some flash blank screen, second time onwards it is working fine.

Issues are, it doesn't show flash blank screen, even in the first time and second one is when I am using android back button it is getting crash.

I am using MAC-OS, Android device Nexus-7 and any emulator also happening same.using JavaScript.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  Based on the details of this question, you are saying tabgroups don't work in Titanium on Android, which may be possible, but I'd think unlikely.  I'd suggest that you create a blank tabgroup project and just run that.  Does it work?  You may have 3 lines of code or 1000.  Not enough information in this question to even point you in a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of windows like, lightweight and heavyweight. If you create a lightweight window in Titanium android than on back button press it will exist from your application.

You can achieve what you want by creating heavyweight window. You can create heavyweight window in titanium by open it as modal window. So put the parameter modal:true when you create a new window. New window will be created as modal window (heavyweight window for titanium android). And then after if you will press back button it will not exit from application.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable android back button or handle it.

```
window.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) 
{
   // Do whatever you want on android back button press.
   // Or leave implementation blank to disable device back button.
});
```